# How to hide datasets label in react-chartjs-2(3.3.0 Version) in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am just getting started learning React a few weeks ago and I tried to make a graph by using react-chartjs-2 library.
I want to hide datasets label, so when I googled it, I found that most information just added options,legend, and display false but it didn't disappear and It just showed label name is false. I will attach the screenshot image[image] below.

I expected that the false should be disappeared but the label names changed to false.

It would be really appreciated your help!

```
const data = {
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: false,
        data: [33, 53, 85, 41, 44, 65],
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing label: false with label: '',

```
const data = {
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: '',
      },
    },
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '',
        data: [33, 53, 85, 41, 44, 65],
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      },
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If you don't mind, can I ask how to hide next to labels?

Comment: I mean when you see the above picture, there is a box next to 'false'!

Comment: I am unable to understand which one. please set  options: {
      legend: {
        display: '',
      },
    },
also, and check

Comment: I am sorry. I am still learning English. The box is above the graph that has a red border and is filled up with green. I am sorry I don't know what should I called in English.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display:false,
           
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'lol',
        },
    },
};
```

set the legend display to false in the options section

edit:
try having the options variable seperate from data and send it as a seperate prop

Comment: Your answer is unclear. In the question there is no variable `options`.

Comment: And it's already false in the question.